# Magento 2 Error - file cannot be removed in magentodir/var/generation/Magento/Framework while i create block and upgrade set up

Tags: magento2, error

> E:\xampp\htdocs\magento-2>php -dmemory_limit=5G bin/magento
>   setup:di:compile The directory
>   "E:/xampp/htdocs/magento-2/var/generation/Magento/Framework" canno t
>   be deleted
>   Warning!rmdir(E:/xampp/htdocs/magento-2/var/generation/Magento/Fram
>   ework): Directory not empty#0
>   E:\xampp\htdocs\magento-2\vendor\magento\framework
>   \Filesystem\Driver\File.php(403):
>   Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Driver\File->dele
>   teDirectory('E:/xampp/htdocs...')

1. E:\xampp\htdocs\magento-2\vendor\magento\framework\Filesystem\Driver\File.php
   (403):
   Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Driver\File->deleteDirectory('E:/xampp/htdoc
   s...')
2. E:\xampp\htdocs\magento-2\setup\src\Magento\Setup\Console\CompilerPreparation
   .php(68):
   Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Driver\File->deleteDirectory('E:/xampp/ht
   docs...')
3. E:\xampp\htdocs\magento-2\vendor\magento\framework\Console\Cli.php(74):
   Magen
   to\Setup\Console\CompilerPreparation->handleCompilerEnvironment()
4. E:\xampp\htdocs\magento-2\bin\magento(22):
   Magento\Framework\Console\Cli->__c onstruct('Magento CLI')
5. {main} PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Cli' not found in
   E:\xampp\htdocs\magento-2\bin\magento  on line 31

> Fatal error: Class 'Cli' not found in
>   E:\xampp\htdocs\magento-2\bin\magento on l ine 31

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Removed your var/generation directory and var/cache directory.**

> You need to remove it manually, if it is ubuntu then locate in your
> magento 2 root directory and run `rm -rf var/generation` and `rm -rf var/cache` command.

**Then try to run below commands in sequence.**

- `php bin/magento setup:di:compile`
- `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`
- `php bin/magento cache:clean`
- `php bin/magento cache:flush`

Comment: mine is a windows system

Comment: @Priya then remove it manually.

Comment: @ManthanDave In windows wamp i removed generation, still showing error like : The directory "C:/wamp64/www/magento2/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App" ca
ot be deleted Warning!rmdir(C:/wamp64/www/magento2/generated/code/Magento/Fram
ork/App): Directory not empty
How to solve the error?

Comment: @ManthanDave Screenshot : https://snipboard.io/FYa9EU.jpg

Comment: I think, one should run the `setup:upgrade` command first and then the `setup:di:compile`

Answer (score 8):

If production mode, put site into maintenance mode first.

```
bin/magento maintenance:enable
bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento setup:di:compile
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
bin/magento cache:flush
// If running as root instead of www-data for example you may need to chown/chmod.
// chown -R www-data:www-data .

bin/magento maintenance:disable
```

Maybe it is because stuff is being generated as bots/users try to access the site?

Note: If you use other locales you would want to setup:static-content:deploy those as well.

I think you can specify multiple after the statup:static-content:deploy en_US en_GB en_NZ etc...

See more here: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli-subcommands-maint.html

You might need to take ownership of the folder first or shell in as the Magento filesystem owner.

Comment: This is definitely the right answer; if you don't enable maintenance mode first you will get spammed with `The directory "/var/www/html/generated/code/Magento" cannot be deleted Warning!rmdir(/var/www/html/generated/code/Magento): Directory not empty` for many directories. Enabling maintenance mode first and waiting a bit for in-flight requests to finish really is the solution here

Comment: This might be the solution since it's possible some users are actively accessing the site and prevents the command to complete due to the directories being created on the fly.